# How to compare specific items in a string python

Tags: python

E.g. in a given input the fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit

```
input = "5000-0000-0000"    
if input[3] != input[5] + 1    
    return false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what `input[3]` and `input[5]` are, you will pretty quickly realize they are characters and not numbers that can be added or compared with mathematical operations (think about what would happen if you wrote `input = "Andrew Francis"`).

You can see this by using `print(type(input[3]))`.

Fortunately, if you have a string that contains only characters that make up a valid number, you can convert it to (for instance) an integer using the `int()` function.  So, try `print(type(int(input[3])))` and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you Larry,

Issue here is the input data is a mock credit card number that includes dashes, how would I go about converting just inputs 3 and 5 to integers and then performing the comparison?

Comment: As cited in the answer, if you call the `int()` function on the string you're interested in, you'll get an integer value.  So, `int(input[3])` returns an integer and `int(input[5])` returns the other integer you're interested in.  Those values can be added to, compared, etc.